# Ruby garbage collection and Puma

Tags: ruby, puma

When using MRI Ruby 2.1.2 with Puma (say 1 worker with 8 threads), when is the GC run? Is it run by the parent worker process when all those threads become idle, or would it be run by the parent process as needed, even when those threads are busy processing requests?

And how would this behaviour be different in Ruby 2.0 (without deferred GC).

[Also asked here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/450#issuecomment-44584881).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been answered on the [Github issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/450#issuecomment-44718261).

> It runs whenever the VM decides to run it. Puma does nothing to control that nor can it really.